# AngularJS remote data with URL parameters

Tags: angularjs

So for an AngularJS app I'm building, we were previously using local JSON files to import data into the app using routing.

```
storiesControllers.controller('StoryDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $sce, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.storyID = $routeParams.storyID;
    $http.get('/story/'+$routeParams.storyID+'.json')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.story = data;
    }); 
}]);
```

However, we're now going to be getting data direct from the server. Only one line changes below:

```
storiesControllers.controller('StoryDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $sce, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.storyID = $routeParams.storyID;
    $http.get('http://website.co.uk/?id='+$routeParams.storyID)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.story = data;
    }); 
}]);
```

This method works at the top level for filtering stories by category:

```
$http.get('http://mywebsite.co.uk/?category=CategoryName')
```

But on the individual story it's completely blank and no data is loaded.

The URL and parameter is correct and working fine, the data on the server is fine and matches exactly the local files, so why does this not work?

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Cross-origin issues?

Comment: No we've allowed CORS etc. As I say, on the top level it works. Listing all stories using an ng-repeat is fine, but when I drill down into the specific ID using routing it's just blank. I know that the call the URL with the parameters is working, but it just doesn't show anything...

Comment: Can you see the call being made to "http://website.co.uk/?id=whatever" in your network tools? When you say it doesn't show anything, is the call being made, is there data coming back, can you see anything in the data object that you are using for $scope.story?

Comment: i have different my search api url is /colum/words not search?colum=words i have to change for a plugin ! any alternative approach !

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the answer was actually found by a colleague of mine. It turns out that instead of:

```
$scope.story = data;
```

I needed to use:

```
$scope.story = data[0];
```

I'm not sure of the relevance of the square brackets 0, but it seems to have fixed it!

Comment: obviously, the object returned an array, or the data-object has the actual data on the first property. You should really log out the data-object, to look at its structure.

[0] just indicates that you extract the first item in an array (or the first property on an object)

Comment: I'm sure it's obvious to you Yngve, but I'm only a beginner to Angular. Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: When you have troubles like that, you want to investigate your data. Use the network tools in the browser to see the response from the API (which might have clued you into the array result) and then when all else fails, console.log(data); That is less of an Angular problem and more REST / AJAX problem.

Comment: @Mike I apologize if my comment came across as condecending or offensive. I meant no such thing, just trying to explain, since you didn't know the meaning of square-brackets in Javascript (it's not an angular-specific concept - it's built-in to Javascript)